# Summations and grouping of terms in an equation used as a constraint in LP

Tags: summation, linear-programming

I am not sure which of the two forms of the equation to use as a constraint in a linear programming model, as I want it to be concise, but also mathematically accurate:

(1) $\sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}} \sum_{j \in \mathcal{J}}  (ax_{i, j} + bx_{j, i}) = c$

(2) $\sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}} \sum_{j \in \mathcal{J}}  ax_{i, j} + \sum_{j \in \mathcal{J}} \sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}} bx_{j, i} = c$

where $x_{i,j}$ is a binary variable. It also holds that $x_{i,j} + x_{j,i} = 1$ (i.e., when $x_{i,j}=1$ then $x_{j,i}=0$ and vice versa).

Are the two forms of the equation considered mathematically the same and therefore I can use either of them? Or is (2) considered more correct/clear because it shows that the iterations on j and i in the second summation are independent of the first summation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those two forms of the constraint are equivalent, whether or not you also enforce $x_{ij}+x_{ji}=1$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response!